# stop automatic image resize on ipad safari

Tags: html, ipad, safari

I notice that ipad automatically resize html tag images when they have a big resolution. Is there a way to preveni this action of safari ipad? I am googling but no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a resource limit, and there is not a way to change it afaict.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html